# Javascript sort doesn't work after push?

Tags: javascript, sorting

What am I doing wrong here: Same results in IE9 and FF.

```
function TestArrayOperationsClick()
{
  function sortNums(a, b)
  {
    return a - b;
  }
  var array = [6, 4, 2, 8];
  console.log("Array 1: " + array); 
  array.sort(sortNums);
  console.log("Sort 1: " + array);
  array.push([1, 5, 10]);
  console.log("Array 2: " + array);
  array.sort(sortNums);
  console.log("Sort 2: " + array);
}
```

Output:

```
LOG: Array 1: 6,4,2,8 

LOG: Sort 1: 2,4,6,8 

LOG: Array 2: 2,4,6,8,1,5,10 

LOG: Sort 2: 2,4,6,8,1,5,10 <- not sorted.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [`array.push(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), you should be passing individual arguments, not an array:

```
array.push(1, 5, 10);
```

For which the final output would then be:

```
Sort 2: 1,2,4,5,6,8,10
```

Otherwise, the result of your push is actually this:

```
[2,4,6,8,[1,5,10]]
```

, though it's not showing clearly when you do `console.log`.

**Edit**: As Jonathan mentioned, if you're looking to append an array of items, [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

[`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't combine `Array`s like the following appears to expect:

```
array.push([1, 5, 10]);
```

Instead of pushing the individual values, it pushes the 2nd `Array` itself, resulting in:

```
[ 2, 4, 6, 8, [ 1, 5, 10 ] ]
```

To append one `Array` onto another, you can use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
array = array.concat([1, 5, 10]);
```

Comment: Array returns a new array. If you want to modify the existing array, by pushing all the elements of another array, you can do: array.push.apply(array, [1, 5, 10])

Comment: @lrn Yeah, if you're adamant about using a mutator, you can use `.push.apply()`. ES6's [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) will also simplify it: `array.push(...[1, 5, 10])`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, for `array.push` you should pass individual arguments as in the eg:

```
array.push(1, 5, 10);
```

But you can do the following to add the content of an array into another array:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(array, [1, 5, 10]);
```

This way, you can pass an array as an argument, since the `apply()` function transforms the second argument (that must be an array) into individual arguments ;)